# Prevent WPF form from jumping up when onscreen-keyboard opens

Tags: wpf, on-screen-keyboard

Please how can we prevent a full screen WPF form from scrolling up when the onscreen keyboard appears?

See the white space below the blue background that appears once the onscreen keyboard opens (slides out)

[image: Sample Screen shot]